# access my custom variables in jmeter's if controller

Tags: jmeter

I try to simply access a custom variable in the if controller:

```
${MyVar} == "none"
```

it seems to always return false (the children don't run even if i replace it with `${MyVar} != "none"`), and I see no errors in my jmeter.log file

Am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 2):

The code generates an exception

`2013/08/14 20:50:43 ERROR - jmeter.control.IfController: If Controller: error while processing [none  ==  "none"]
 org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "none" is not defined. (<cmd>#1)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3750)`

Use `doule quotes` around the variable and it should fix the problem.

```
"${MyVar}" == "none"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll check it soon. Where did you find this exception? Wasn't it supposed to be in jmeter.log?

Comment: Yes its in jmeter.log. Starting from 2.9 you can also view jmeter.log in the UI it self by clicking the "options/log viewer" or 2nd from top right button on toolbar.